# How to use a separate input history for helm-swoop?

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

I know that I can [use a separate input history](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12338) for helm-swoop by adding the following code to helm-swoop.el, but I don't want to edit the package source code.

```
:history 'my-helm-swoop-input-history
```

I've tried the following codes, but it doesn't work (no history at all when I use M-p during my-helm-swoop):

```
(defvar my-helm-swoop-input-history nil)
(defun my-helm-swoop() (interactive) (let ((minibuffer-history 'my-helm-swoop-input-history)) (helm-swoop)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work for two reasons:

1. Do not quote `my-helm-swoop-input-history` in the `let`-binding. You want its value, not the symbol.
2. Your `minibuffer-history` does not survive the `let` scope.

Try this, it works for me:

```
(defun my-helm-swoop() (interactive)
       (setq my-helm-swoop-input-history
             (let ((minibuffer-history my-helm-swoop-input-history)) 
               (helm-swoop) minibuffer-history)))
```